# How to create filters in Gmail with "OR" condition in "Has the words"

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I need to create a filter with an `OR` condition in `Has the words` to return results where either one of the specified words occurs in the body of the mail.

How to achieve this in Gmail?

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/276499/build-advanced-gmail-filters-and-persistent-searches it might be helpfull

Answer (score 11):

If the word(s) has(ve) spaces in them, we enclose with double quotes like `(("An Apple" OR "Three Apples"))`

Answer (score 10):

You can use brackets like this:

> ((word1 OR word2 OR word3))